# How to pass a string as a parameter into a javascript function from a View?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've just started to work with ASP.NET MVC projects, I have gotten past the basics, but I came across with a problem recently, I can't pass a string as a id from a View.

So far, I've been passing the id to a javascript function like this:

```
<script>app.init( <%: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() %>)</script>
```

This calls the following javascript function:

```
var app = {};
(function (app) {
    var _id;
    app.init = function (id) {
        _id = id;
    }
    app.id = function () {
        return _id;
    }
})(app);
```

I'm doing this because I need to work with the id to perform operations like submits and ajax calls in javascript (I prefer working with javascript).

So far this has worked with int values, but when I tried to pass a string it fails. For example if I try to access to this url localhost:65097/Device/Edit/D2C02 it shows the following error:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'D2C02' is undefined
```

When I check the generated html code, the call to the function looked like this:

```
<script>app.init(D2C02)</script>
```

Shouldn't the id be passed as 'D2C02' like a string, instead of just D2C02 like a variable? Because that's what I'm understading the browser thinks the id D2C02 represents. How can I make sure the id value is passed on to the javascript function as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToString()` just converts something to a string - but that's a C# string, not a JS string. So the easiest solution is to add quotes assuming the value can never contain quotes, too:

```
<script>app.init("<%: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() %>")</script>
```

If it may contain quotes you can either perform a simple replacement to backslash-escape them or run the string through a JSON serializer that takes care of turning it into a valid JavaScript string.

Comment: I tried to wrap it in quotes but it still tried to pass it as a variable name

Comment: I'm sorry, it does work, I hard refreshed my page and it worked, sometimes I forget to do the basic stuff due to my exasperation, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

app.init("<%......%>");

Otherwise you are just posting in a variable name and not string.  The ToString() method in c# doesn't wrap the vale in quotes

Comment: I'm sorry, it does work, I hard refreshed my page and it worked, sometimes I forget to do the basic stuff due to my exasperation, still had to choose a correct answer and had to flip a coin to decide. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would use is to do something like this, to make things a bit more semantic -- this is overly simplified to demonstrate:

```
<body>
    <input id="myId" type="hidden" value="<%: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() %>" />

...
<script language="text/javascript">
    function getId() {
        return document.getElementById("myId").value;
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error:
`Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: `data-` attributes would be much more appropriate than a hidden field.